# Cannot install package using composer in NetBeans

Tags: netbeans-7, symfony-2.1, composer-php

I'm using symfony2.1 on XAMPP, with NetBeans 7.3 as the IDE. And I want to install `friendofsymfony/rest-bundle` package by adding these line on require section

`"friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle": "0.11.0",`

And then I right click on project, then Composer > Update

What I get on output window is

```
D:\xampp\php\php.exe C:\ProgramData\Composer\bin\composer --ansi --no-interaction update

# This file must be saved with Unix line endings, or cygwin will choke

DIR=`dirname "$0"`;
DIRECTORY=$(cd "${DIR}" && pwd)

if command -v 'cygpath' >/dev/null 2>&1; then
  DIRECTORY=`cygpath -m $DIRECTORY`;
fi

PHAR="$(echo $DIRECTORY | sed 's/ /\ /g')/composer.phar"
php "${PHAR}" $*
Done.
```

And the package is not installed.

Am I doing it right? How to install the package correctly using Composer on NetBeans?

Comment: I'd suggest contacting netbeans support, because this definitely looks like a netbeans specific error.

Comment: Read the message and do what it sais: make sure the `composer.lock` file is saved with Unix line endings (`\n`) and not the Windows ones (`\n\r`).

Comment: I check using Notepad++, set to show line ending and it shows LF (\n). I also post this question to NetBeans forums

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do you use Windows?
Tools -> PHP -> Composer -> Composer: select the composer.phar file!

Then try again.

Comment: Yes, I use Windows. The composer path is set to `C:\ProgramData\Composer\bin\composer`

Comment: click on search... and select: C:\ProgramData\Composer\bin\composer.phar

Comment: Ahh, now it's working. I didn't realize that composer and composer.phar is different, because when in command prompt I user composer. Thanks Simone.